# Run a jQuery function called from another function

Tags: jquery, function, external

I really don't know how to express this question. But what I'm trying to achieve is to run/call a jQuery function from another JavaScript (non jQuery) function.

I'm trying to add elements to [JQ carousel.](http://5509.github.com/jq.carousel/)

This is how it is supposed to be done: by clicking on a button. :

```
$('#carousel_add').on('click', function(ev) {
  $carousel.carousel('reset');
  $carousel.append('<div class="carousel_box"> Page '+(z)+' <br/><img src="http://place.to/my/picture/file'+dir+'/0'+z+'.png" width="100px" height="50px"> </div>');
  $carousel.carousel('refresh');
  document.getElementById('carousel_next').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('carousel_prev').disabled = true;
});
```

I'm trying to do it without the adding button. I want that a button, which triggers a JavaScript function, triggers then the jQuery adding function for the Carousel. The problem I am having is that it says that the carousel variable is undefined, which I can understand because is not within the function's scope.

Example:

HTML ->

```
<input type="button" value="Load Pages" function="loadPages();">
```

JavaScript (No jQuery involved)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadPages()
{
myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "http://path.to/image/file.png";
//The image is loaded.
//Now I want to add this image to the JQ Carousel
addCarousel(myImage.src);
}
</script>
```

JavaScript (jQuery based carousel -> JQ Carousel)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var $carousel = $('#carousel').carousel({
        group: 6,
        indicator: false
      }),
      $prev = $('#carousel_prev'),
      $next = $('#carousel_next'),
       set_state = function() {
        var state = $carousel.carousel('getMoveState');
        switch ( state ) {
        case 'min':
          $prev.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
          $next.prop('disabled', '');
          break;
        case 'max':
          $prev.prop('disabled', '');
          $next.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
          break;
        case true:
          $prev.prop('disabled', '');
          $next.prop('disabled', '');
          break;
        default:
          $prev.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
          $next.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
      };
      num = 1;

    $('#carousel_prev').on('click', function(ev) {
      $carousel.carousel('prev');
    });
    $('#carousel_next').on('click', function(ev) {
      $carousel.carousel('next');
    });
    // ...
    $carousel.bind({
      'Carousel.next': function() {
        set_state();
      },
      'Carousel.prev': function() {
        set_state();
      }
    });

</script>
```

Now the function that is supposed to add it

```
function addCarousel(image)
{
      $carousel.carousel('reset');
      $carousel.append('<div class="carousel_box"> Page '+(num++)+' <br/><img src="'+image+'" width="100px"> </div>');
      $carousel.carousel('refresh');
      document.getElementById('carousel_next').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('carousel_prev').disabled = true;
    })


}
```

The HTML where the carousel resides:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel_inner">

    <div class="carousel_box"> Page 1 <br/><img src="http://path/to/image/file.png" width="100px"></div>
   </div>

   </div>
  <p class="btns">
    <input type="button" id="carousel_prev" value="prev" disabled>
    <input type="button" id="carousel_next" value="next" >
    <input type="button" id="carousel_add" value="add">
  </p>
</div>
```

I'm getting $carousel is undefined, though it was previously declared on the page. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the `$carousel` outside of the `document.ready` function.

like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $carousel = null;
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $carousel = $('#carousel').carousel({//notice i removed "var "
        group: 6,
        indicator: false
     }),
....
```

Earlier, variable `$carousel` was only visible inside the anonymous handler of the `document.ready` event. Moving it out side, will give global visibility to that variable. So, now you can use that variable from anywhere in your script.

Also, be-aware of updating `$carousel`. Because the same value will be reflected in all other places you have referenced `$carousel`.

Answer (score 0):

`$carousel` is not visible out of the `document.ready` scope, declare `$carousel` out of your `document.ready`.

```
var $carousel; 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $carousel = $('#carousel').carousel({...
```

Comment: You're a genius! :p Thanks a lot! It did the job perfectly XD